# How can I map an FTP share to a letter drive in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, router, ftp

I purchased an external HDD to use with my Netgear Nighthawk router. I enabled FTP access to this drive on my router and added it as a network location on Windows 10. I'm able to access this folder via the File Explorer and transfer files between my computer and the HDD. My router describes this network location as a share folder. This virtual folder has no physical path associated with it, and as such I don't know how to access it via the command line with a command like 'cd'. I would like to be able to map this network location to a letter drive on Windows 10. I have tried freeware such as FTPUSE, but despite it saying it successfully mapped the FTP server, no new letter drives come up.

Another issue I am having is that if I transfer a file from my computer to the network folder, and then unplug the HDD from my router and connect it to my computer, I can't see any of the files on the HDD that I transferred via FTP. There are no hidden folders on the drive, and the entire HDD is one single NTFS partition. The issue persists if I transfer a file from my computer directly to the HDD followed by plugging the drive back into the router and then accessing it via FTP - I can't see any of the files I transferred in this fashion! What gives?

Netgear Nighthawk R7000
Supported protocols: HTTP(S)/FTP
WD_BLACK P10 Game Drive (5TB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to map an FTP connection to a drive letter natively in Windows. However, your router's [manual](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R7000/R7000_UM.pdf) says that it supports SMB shares, so you should be able to navigate to `\\readyshare` from your Windows PC and access the files that way. That also means that you can map it as a network drive.

As for the file transfers not "sticking' - it may have something to do with NTFS permissions. If this drive is going to be primarily attached to the router for file sharing, I'd recommend reformatting it as ext4 if possible. If you can't reformat it as ext4, try to reformat the drive with NTFS. I looked up the WD_BLACK P10 and they all come from the factory exFAT, but you mention yours is NTFS so I assume you've formatted it before.

Answer (score 0):

FTP is really not the way to make files accessible to Windows.
Even though Explorer has some limited support for it it goes totally against the native way of working for Windows.
I'm sure you router can share it as a regular WIndows Share (aka SMB protocol).

I just took a quick look at the R7000 manual and apparently it shares the hardisk via SMB by default (no need to configure anything) using the servername "readyshare".
Just open `\\readyshare` in Explorer and it should show you the harddisk and you can map it as a network-drive with a drive-letter as well.

Why you can't see the files if you move the disk from router to PC and vice-versa is an entirely different matter.
I cant; say for certain wihtout playing around with a R700 myself, but I can make an educated guess.
It most likely has to do with the FTP server on the router storing the files in a folder that is hidden for your Windows computer.
The FTP server has no knowledge whatsoever about your Windows system and will store the files on the disk using its own internal user-account that is only valid on the router.
When you look at the disk while connected to the computer those files will be hidden as they belong the a different user (the FTP server).
You might be able to see them in Windows if you enbale "Show hidden and system files" in Explorer.

The other possiblity is that you router doesn't understand NTFS at all (many routers don't) and can't actually store them, but doesn't give a meanigfull error that is understood by Windows. 
In that case your files are most probably lost.